How to remove obligation to run as administrator in Windows?
A while ago, I changed C:\WINDOWS\system32\Taskmgr.exe on my professional  Windows 10 computer to always run as administrator. I unfortunately don't remember how I did.
Now, my company policy changed, and my user is not administrator anymore. I have a second user with administrative rights, but I need to write the password each time I want to run the task manager. I am still able to run it as myself, but I need to enter my password.
It is not dramatic but I would like to remove this. How can I do that. I saw a lot of answers telling I need to go to Compatibility tab on the .exe, but I don't have it, maybe it is restricted by my company.



Check your User Account Control settings and publish them in the question. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/application-security/application-control/user-account-control/settings-and-configuration https://imgur.com/a/K3HL3LK

This sounds like a case where you will need to get a system Administrator to reinstall Windows since you are unable to detail how you elevated the permissions of Task Manager. So, neither an Administrator on the system nor anyone here can explain how to reverse the process. An in-place repair of Windows should be enough, but changing the permissions on system files, is never recommended for this exact reason.

Are you sure you changed something? Because Task Manager has some peculiar properties: It is set to auto-elevate, if at all possible. Even before your change, on any Windows system. Depending on how your rights got taken away, this could be the problem source.

Reinstalling the OS is a rather extreme approach...

"Now, my company policy changed, and my user is not administrator anymore." Obey the company policy. It's a good one. You should not be running as Admin in Windows, any more than a linux user should run as root. Getting Admin privileges by entering a password is an important security feature.

Try this batch file with task manager not running:
set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER
taskmgr

If it works; you can create a shortcut to launch it.

Thank, it works. It is a great and easy workaround.

Interesting. That may work, but I'm guessing it loses you things like the ability to right-click on the taskbar clock and select "Task Manager". Which I know is how I always run it. Still seems like something worth solving "for real".

I will accept this as answer. Although it is not solved "for real", this workaround will be enough until I will reinstall my computer (and I did not find another working way).
And for other abilities like right-click in the taskbar as said by @FeRD, I still can use it, I "just" have to enter my password.

That's an interesting question. Why? Because the task manager runs by default with highestAvailable privilege, meaning that if you're an Admin - it'll run elevated, otherwise it won't.
Also: there's no compatibility tab in System32 folder, by design. So how do you force something that's in there to always run as Admin? Well, there are several ways, and since I (and obviously - you ;]) have no idea what you did before, let me explore some of the possibilities:


The simplest and most well-known: create a shortcut to whatever in System32 you want to run as Admin, open its Properties -> Advanced (button in the "Shortcut" tab) -> check Run as administrator. Done.
But wait, it gets more interesting. Using task manager as an example: if you click on the Start menu and start typing task manager it'll appear at the top of the list. Right click on the item, select Open file location, and you'll end up... no, not in the System32 folder. It'll be

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools

Now guess what happens if you overwrite the shortcut there with the one you just created (or just change the properties of an existing one)?
Yes, launching task manager via Start menu now requires Admin elevation.




Unfortunately, the above solution won't work if you right click on the Start menu and choose task manager from the list. Why? Because it's a different shortcut of course!
The more detailed explanation is as follows:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools

is actually accessible by the so-called %ALLUSERSPROFILE% (which equals C:\ProgramData and also C:\Users\All Users) and, as the name suggests, changes the behavior of - in our example: task manager ran via searching in start menu - for each user (even the ones created after the change).
The right click on the start menu shortcuts are located elsewhere - in

C:\Users<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX

and (as far as I know, correct me if I'm wrong) are user-specific, meaning that the shortcuts have to be modified for every (existing) user separately. The shortcut to the task manager is in the Group2 folder - modify the shortcut there and the right click on the start menu option is done.




The only thing left is a Ctrl+Alt+Del and Ctrl+Shift+Tab combination. The one sure way to tackle it that I know of is to use Windows registry feature called Image File Execution Options. This is an advanced debugging option (often used by malware) that, when set, will run the application of your choice instead of whatever you clicked on. And yes, It MAY be the same application, but with a surprise ;]
To manage the feature run regedit and navigate to the following key:

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options

If taskmgr.exe is not present there you need to create a new key named taskmgr.exe, right click it and add a new string value (REG_SZ). The name of the value should be Debugger, and the value data is the path to the application you want to run instead of the task manager (in our example). To try it out just put calc.exe there - and try to run the task manager ;]
A crude but working example of a command that will always elevate the task manager (copy as a single line and put in the value data of the Debugger key):

cmd.exe /Q /C "@AT>NUL||echo set shell=CreateObject("Shell.Application"):shell.ShellExecute "taskmgr.exe",,"%CD%", "runas", 1:set shell=nothing>%temp%\n0.vbs&start %temp%\n0.vbs /realtime& timeout 1 /NOBREAK>nul& del /Q %temp%\n0.vbs&cls&exit"




Note: the steps described in #3 will override both #1 and #2!

Depending on how you start Task Manager, you didn't change that on the executable itself but on a shortcut, e.g. the shortcut in start menu.


This was already not checked. And I see the little adminstrator icon on the exe itself.

Because your user is not an administrator, you cannot see the Compatibilty tab.
Log out and back in as your administrator user, and open the properties again.
This time you will see the compatibility tab where the "Always run as Admin" is checked. Uncheck this to revert back to how it used to be.

Unfortunately, the tab is also not there on my admin account. Maybe it's blocked by policy. Is there a workaround to do it without this tab, by example in the Windows registry?

Not to my knowledge. On my pc the compatibility tab is there.

This property is per-user, I believe. So if you set the property in one user account, you will need to remove the property in that user account. You should talk with your IT staff about temporarily adding your regular account as local admin under their supervision, removing the flag, then removing the local admin.

The Compatibility tab is not available on all (system) applications. It isn’t available on Task Manager. However, this Q/A has information on how this information is saved.

@DanielB it is on my computer for taskmgr.exe

@LPChip Not mine. And in fact, if you run the Program Compatibility Troubleshooter, even as Administrator, and try to force it to modify C:\Windows\System32\Taskmgr.exe, it refuses with a "The specified path contains a program that cannot be changed by this troubleshooter." message.

I'm also confused because, as @mrd83 says, Task Manager no longer needs to be Run as Administrator. I remember back in Windows 7, it would launch showing only the current user's tasks, and there was a link at the bottom of the window to elevate the process and show all tasks. That link isn't there in Windows 10, and if you're a user with the ability to run as Administrator the Task Manager opens as elevated as it's going to get.

I decided that the compatibility information had to be stored in the registry somewhere, so I launched regedit.exe went searching.
What I eventually found was Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers, a registry key which on my system contains two values:

C:\GSmartControl\gsmartcontrol.exe
C:\Program Files\DebugView++\DebugView++.exe

Both are set to ~ RUNASADMIN, and both are indeed programs I've chosen to have Run as Administrator by default.
So you could try checking there, and if there's an entry for C:\Windows\System32\Taskmgr.exe, just delete it.

This sounded promising. However, I don't have a Layers "folder" under AppCompatFlags". I looked under AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Store, but there is no Taskmgr.exe, although there are other paths to some .exe.

@DamienR Darn. Did you try just blindly searching the registry for Taskmgr.exe? See if anything else worth investigating turned up?

i'm guessing CompatibilityAssistant\Store is (like it says) for programs that've been customized using the Assistant, which as I mentioned in a comment on the longer answer above, will refuse to even touch Taskmgr.exe no matter how hard you try to force it to. Layers is probably for applications that've been customized using the Explorer properties dialog and/or by (shift?-)right-clicking on Start menu entries, which is definitely how I customized the two applications mentioned above.

yes, I tried regscanner to search all instances of Taskmrg and compared it with a colleague, but I found nothing of intersest unfortunately.

Is your account in any local groups on the machine?  Being in the “Network Configuration Operators” group (possibly others as well) brings up a UAC prompt asking for your current, non-admin credentials to open Task Manager.
Try running:
Get-LocalGroupMember “Network Configuration Operators”

in PowerShell, or check in lusrmgr.msc
It’s possible the account is being added to the group via Group Policy, in which case you won’t be able to remove yourself permanently.  If you added yourself to the group, you can simply remove yourself to resolve the issue, though you will need to be an administrator to manage advanced network settings (static IP, etc.)

I ran the command but it did not display anything. I think I am therefore not part of this group.
